# Como clonar um objeto no FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, fabric.js

No FabricJs, através da função `canvas.getActiveObject()` é possível retornar o valor do objeto ativo atualmente.

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de clonar esse objeto e adicioná-lo ao canvas, com as mesmas proporções e modificações atuais.

Exemplo:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {preserveObjectStacking: true});


document.querySelector('#adicionar-objeto').addEventListener('click', function () {

    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (image) {

        image.scale(0.3);

        image.opacity = .7;

        canvas.add(image);

        canvas.centerObject(image);
   });

})

document.querySelector('#clonar-objeto').addEventListener('click', function () {
      var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

      // Quero clonar esse objeto aqui e adicioná-lo ao canvas
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há um método para clonar objetos.

```
document.querySelector('#clonar-objeto').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var obj = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveObject());
    obj.set("top", 0);
    obj.set("left", 0);
    canvas.add(obj);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Para clonar um objeto (ou mais objeto) no JavaScript você pode utilizar o método [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
    const origem = {
       a: 1,
       b: 2
    };

    const destino = Object.assign({}, origem);

    console.log(origem, destino);
```

Comment: Não é para clonar o objeto do Javascript, mas do canvas. A resposta não responde à pergunta.